# how to use column of tokenized sentences to further tokenize into words

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

i have tokenized a text in a column into a new column 'token_sentences' of sentence tokens.
i want to use 'token_sentences' column to create a new column 'token_words' containing tokenized words.

df i am using

```
article_id      article_text                                       
1           Maria Sharapova has basically no friends as te...   
2           Roger Federer advance...    
3           Roger Federer has revealed that organisers of ...   
4           Kei Nishikori will try to end his long losing ...
```

added `token_sentences` column

```
article_id      article_text                                      token_sentences                          
1           Maria Sharapova has basically no friends as te...    [Maria Sharapova has basically no friends as te    
2           Roger Federer advance...                             [Roger Federer advance...
3           Roger Federer has revealed that organisers of ...    [Roger Federer has revealed that organisers of...
4           Kei Nishikori will try to end his long losing ...    [Kei Nishikori will try to end his long losing...
```

which is a list of sentences in every row.
i am unable to flatten the list in `token_sentences` column to be able to used in the next step

i want use `token_sentences` column 
to make the df look like

```
article_id  article_text    token_sentences                         token_words                       
1           Maria...        ["Maria Sharapova..",["..."]]           [Maria, Sharapova, has, basically, no, friends,...]       
2           Roger...        ["Roger Federer advanced  ...",["..."]] [Roger,Federer,...]
3           Roger...        ["Roger Federer...",["..."]]            [Roger ,Federer,...]
4           Kei ...         ["Kei Nishikori will try...",["..."]]   [Kei,Nishikori,will,try,...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
def join(token_sentences):
    return " ".join(token_sentences)

new_df = df['token_sentences'].apply(join).apply(word_tokenize)
```

new_df will be your token sentences then add this df to your df like
join function for joining your sentences i didn't realise sentences were lists too if sentences not list then just remove the `.apply(join)`

```
df['token_words'] = new_df
```

install nltk

```
pip install nltk
```

Comment: that was helpful. i have added a new column in the df by `data['token_Words'] = data['token_sentences'].apply(lambda x: join(x)).apply(word_tokenize)`
but i am a little confused about how the join() function is working. Could you please briefly explain that?

Comment: `apply` works the column you chose to run function and the function will get the value of every row in the column one by one and returns the result and change the value of the column. you can learn more about this from pandas documentation `apply` is very useful if u can utilize.

Comment: i was asking about the `join()` function. why didnt you use the _python built-in join()_ with the `df[toke_sentence]` column directly, instead of using it through function?

Comment: Just trying to let you know there is something like this

Comment: ookay!!! actually i couldnt make join() work with the df column directly. Your approach really worked.